# OS X graphics framework able to achieve 60 Hz rendering based on custom buffer?

Tags: macos

What are approaches that enable one to achieve 60 Hz rendering performance based on custom / self-provided RGB/RGBA buffer?

I have a project with functional rendering logic that refreshes an in-memory RBBA buffer for its display.

I'm simply looking for a way to drive a windowed display surface or view based on this on OS X.

Based on my research, Quartz or Core Graphics appears to have the requisite primitives however lacks the performance to do this at the required refresh rate. Also enabling this in concert with NSTimer's doesn't have the right refresh cadence or resolution to get to 60 FPS (according to Apple's documentation).

Comment: You want to look at CADisplayLink: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink

Answer (score 0):

I am going forward with a scrappy implementation based on CGDataProviderCreateWithData to CGImageRef to NSImage to NSImageView based on some encouraging prototype results.

I am refreshing said buffer based on an NSTimer with a 0.016 sec refresh interval.

Still would love to know what better alternatives exist out there.

Code snippet follows, putting it out there in case it helps.

```
// byteBuffer is a 306 x 242 uint8_t* based RGBA (4 byte per pixel ) buffer.
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(byteBuffer, byteBuffer, 306 * 242 * 4, NULL);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(306, 242, 8, 32, 306 * 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big, dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

CGSize size = { 306, 242 };
// maintain a reference to NSImage* in this controller based code
self.nsImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage: image size: size];
// set new image on NSImageView (self.myView)
self.myView.image = self.nsImage;
```

The above code can be called from the following NSTimer / selector combination:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.016 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)timer {
    // Here you can call your (above) update buffer code
    [self updateView];
    [self.myView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```